# I'm trying to remove a comma and I can't seem to reach it, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

seems so easy but I can't reach a comma in my HTML and just remove it from the page. Must be something easy I'm missing. Thanks for the help.

My HTML snippet is as follows:

```
<div id="heightWeightContainer" class="inlineBlock"><span id="height" class="sans14 topData bold"></span>,</div>
```

You'll see the comma at the end of the line.

I've tried a few different ways of getting rid of this guy.

```
$('#heightWeightContainer').html().replace(",","");
$('#heightWeightContainer').text().replace(",","");
$('#height').parent().text().replace(',','');
```

I even tried pure JS with getElementById & .replace but nothing seems to get it.

I can add that these lines of code work in the console so I'm not sure why it wouldn't in my js file.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are calling the function before the DOM is ready? Or your function is never being called? Add some debug messages to check if it is being called

Comment: you aren't changing the dom, just replacing in a string that never gets used anywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just replacing the `,` and nothing doing with the returning string. You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**  with callback function to update the content. Add global flag `'g'` if you want to remove all occurrence

```
$('#heightWeightContainer').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(",", "")
});
```

Or you can replace only text in text node , which will not harm any event bind to the inner html elements. Use **[`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)** to get children including text and comment nodes. Iterate over them using **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**

```
$('#heightWeightContainer').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(',', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Better to not do HTML replacement. You're going to destroy and handlers or data  inside `heightWeightContainer`.

Comment: @squint, could you elaborate it?

Comment: also note that only first occurrence will get replaced this way

Comment: @nevermind: This takes the current DOM structure in the `heightWeightContainer`, serializes it to HTML and passes it to the callback where the `.replace()` is done and new HTML is returned. That returned HTML gets parsed and turned into new DOM nodes which replace the existing ones. If there were any event handlers or other data associated with those old nodes, all that data gets destroyed. I know this was the OP's approach, but this is a solution to avoid.

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/drosrhnv/) that shows why this solution is  bad. click the red text, then the button, then the red text again.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked perfectly! I want to understand it more though. Thanks to @squint for his seemingly great explanation but I'm still confused about what happened in the function, using i and v, and then g at the end. If you guys can help explain further or point me in a direction, that would be awesome. I'm a junior dev by the way, working my way up and trying to learn everything! thanks again!

Comment: @nyhunter77: The `'g'` at the end is meaningless. It shouldn't be there. The rest is an iterator, which really isn't needed here since there'll be only one element. The `v` gives you the HTML from the existing DOM, and the `i` is the index of the current element in the collection.

Comment: @nevermind: Excellent approach, as long as there aren't any other comma-only text nodes. But yes, that's more of a DOM centric way rather than HTML manipulation. Just keep in mind that `this.remove()` is operating on a DOM element, which will work in newer browsers but not older ones.

Comment: @squint, thanks, I see Pranav changed the code back, originally it didn't have a 'g'.  So if i understand correctly, I can iterate through my html elements just using a function and i and v? If I had more elements and needed to search through them all, this would do it? If so, this is an amazing piece of knowledge, thanks to all.

Comment: Yes, thanks... And now we have perfect answer. @Pranav, sorry for extra-comments, but it was but it was worth it, for many of us...

Comment: @nyhunter77: Yes, if you're familiar with jQuery's `.each()` method, this is almost the same, except that it's specialized for HTML manipulation so that it gives you the current HTML serialization of the DOM and lets you return the new HTML to create the new DOM. There are several jQuery methods that have this built-in iterator ability.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @squint, thanks to nevermind as well for the alternate or possibly better answer? I'm adding them to my JS book of knowledge for continued use. Thanks to Pranav as well for starting us off.